# Why is DKIM configuration testing not working the same for every test site?

Tags: dkim, spf, dmarc

basically, I have setup spk, dkim and dmarc for mail authentication. For this, I used [this](https://www.emailarchitect.net/domainkeys/kb/dkim_exchange_2007_2010_2013.aspx) tuto. All worked correctly and I got this result:

[image]
seems like everything OK.

Now to confirm everything is working correctly, I have tried, on and another site ([here](https://dmarcguide.globalcyberalliance.org)), But seems like dkim does not work. I am new in this technology. I have read about dkim, spf, dmarc. But I have not practical experiment with it.
[image]

Why are these site giving a different result?
I am new in this technology I want to know Where I should start to solve this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you did not specify any DKIM selector on the second test site. And if the one you use for your site is not one of the several the test site tried then it will fail to check for a DKIM DNS record.

Apart from that the second test site seems to have more strict and non-standard requirements than the first site. While it successfully validated a domain I own with a non-standard DKIM selector it failed to verify DKIM setup on gmail.com with the current selector 20161025. The reason might be that my DKIM DNS record included the recommended (but not required) `v=DKIM1` at the beginning while the record for gmail.com did not.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have got the exact error why trying gmail.com. Now I am not sure if it is really an error: https://dmarcguide.globalcyberalliance.org/#/tool-select?d=gmail.com&r=sm&s=none&lang=en

Comment: @dmx: see my edited answer. The second test site seems to be slightly buggy and seems to require a setup which while recommended is not strongly required. Given that it is unknown how your setup looks like it is unknown if this is the problem you have too.